# SQL: how to select next id given an id

Tags: sql

There is one table T ( id integer, primary key ( id). 
I want a parameterized query that, given id i:
will return next consecutive id, 
if i = biggest id in T, query should return the smallest id in T (cyclical)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select the smallest id over the value @i (if any), and the smallest id, then get the largest:

```
select max(id)
from (
  select top 1 id
  from T
  where id > @i
  order by id
  union all
  select top 1 id
  from T
  order by id
) x
```

Or perhaps:

```
select max(id)
from (
  select min(id) as id
  from T
  where id > @i
  union all
  select min(id)
  from T
) x
```

Comment: thanks, exactly what I was looking for, now I need to check if max/min works on strings.. it does.

Comment: @Marcin: Max and min works on strings, but it does a textual comparison. If you have numerical vales stored as strings, you have to convert them to numbers in the query, as for example '2' > '10'.

Comment: So how can I find the previous ID based on this method?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be what you're looking for:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ProcName
(
    @ID INTEGER
)
AS
SELECT TOP 1 id
FROM table
WHERE id > @ID
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: the OP wants it to return the smallest ID again when the greatest ID has been reached (cyclic)...

Comment: How is this meeting the OP's cyclical behavior when id>= max?